# UrlHelper returning Url that executes another method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Im doing a tutorial about Web APIs, I have 2 controllers, one repo and one factory that returns the models, the response is in json and returns the data and the url.

This is my modelFactory:

```
public class ModelFactory : IModelFactory
{
    private UrlHelper _UrlHelper;

    public ModelFactory(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(request);
    }

    public FoodModel Create(Food food)
    {
        return new FoodModel()
        {
            Url = _UrlHelper.Link("Food", new { foodid = food.Id }),
            Description = food.Description,
            Measures = food.Measures.Select(m => Create(m))
        };
    }

    public MeasureModel Create(Measure measure)
    {
        MeasureModel measureModel  = new MeasureModel
        {
            Url = _UrlHelper.Link("Food", new { foodid = measure.Food.Id, measures = measure.Id }),
            Description = measure.Description,
            Calories = Math.Round(measure.Calories)
        };

        return measureModel;
    }
}
```

These are my routes in my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings
    .Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept",
                                  "text/html",
                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
                                  true,
                                  "application/json"));

    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Food",
        routeTemplate: "api/nutrition/foods/{foodid}",
        defaults: new { controller = "foods", foodid = RouteParameter.Optional });

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Measures",
        routeTemplate: "api/nutrition/foods/{foodid}/measures/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "measures", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

And this is my MeasuresController:

```
public class MeasuresController : BaseApiController
{
    public MeasuresController(ICountingKsRepository repo) : base(repo) { }

    public IEnumerable<MeasureModel> Get(int foodid)
    {
        var results = TheRepository.GetMeasuresForFood(foodid)
            .ToList()
            .Select(m => TheModelFactory.Create(m));

        return results;
    }

    public MeasureModel Get(int foodid,int id)
    {

        var results = TheRepository.GetMeasure(id);

        if(results.Food.Id == foodid)
        {
            return TheModelFactory.Create(results);
        }

        return new MeasureModel
        {
            Description = "No Food id associated with this Measure",
            Calories = 0,
            Url = ""
        };
    }

}
```

now, Im using fiddler with the JSONview plugin for Chrome and this is the structure of my json when I call Get(int foodid)

I go to: http://localhost:8901/api/nutrition/foods/1/measures

```
[
   {
      Url: "http://localhost:8901/api/nutrition/foods/1?measures=1",
      Description: "1 Cup",
      Calories: 1628
   },
   {
      Url: "http://localhost:8901/api/nutrition/foods/1?measures=2",
      Description: "1 Tbsp",
      Calories: 102
   }
]
```

If I want to go, lets say http://localhost:8901/api/nutrition/foods/1?measures=2 It executes the Get(int foodid) instead of Get(int foodid, int id) but if I change the Url to http://localhost:8901/api/nutrition/foods/1/measures/2

It goes to the correct method.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem

In my method:

```
public MeasureModel Create(Measure measure)
{
    MeasureModel measureModel  = new MeasureModel
    {
        Url = _UrlHelper.Link("Food", new { foodid = measure.Food.Id, measures = measure.Id }),
        Description = measure.Description,
        Calories = Math.Round(measure.Calories)
    };

    return measureModel;
}
```

The Url was routing to Food instead of Measures, so I needed to change the Url property with this:

```
Url = _UrlHelper.Link("Measures", new { foodid = measure.Food.Id, measures = measure.Id })
```